# DatePicker and AutoComplete methods not visible using JQuery 2.1.1 (jquery-ui-1.10.4) and VS2012 Pro

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, datepicker

I'm using VS2012 Pro and I've developed a MVC 4 app with this product.

I'm facing a problem during upgrade from Jquery 1.8.2(jquery-ui-1.8.24) to JQuery 2.1.1 (jquery-ui-1.10.4). The upgrade took place after installing all available updates of NuGet package.

To be more specific when I'm typing `$('#SomeField')` inside a script and right after the dot (.) no option datepicker or autocomplete is visible.

In a few words this means that my MVC4 app that had this code inside ( for example `$('#SomeField').datepicker().val()` ) doesn't work as it should.

I've also tried to create a new MVC 4 app and to test one model with its controller as well as its views to see if it works alone (I've also executed all available updates of NuGet package). Unfortunately, the problem still remained.

Is there a bug or is it my fault after upgrade?